# Saltos de línea en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este código PHP:

```
$fields     = array('categoria' => 'Categoría', 'name' => 'Nombre', 'phone' => 'Teléfono', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Detalles');
```

y este es el resultado:

[image: resultado en una sola línea]

¿Cómo hago para tener saltos de línea? es decir que se vea de la siguiente manera:

Categoría: Diseño Editorial

Detalles: scsAC

Email: XXXXXXX

.....

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente con [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) puedes realizarlo:

```
$fields = array('categoria' => 'Categoría', 'name' => 'Nombre', 'phone' => 'Teléfono', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Detalles');

foreach ($fields as $value => $key) {

    echo "{$key}: {$value}<br>";
}
```

Según el salto lo puedes realizar con `PHP_EOL` o con `<br>` según tus necesidades.

[Ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0905c68a1c607957c5db67ae203516075c13b227)

**Edit:**

Para obtener el valor de tu `$_POST` cual tiene que tener la misma `clave (key)` lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
$posts = ['categoria' => 'zapato', 'name' => 'nike', 'phone' => '666666', 'email' => 'ejemplo@mail.com', 'message' => 'hola la quiero'];

$fields = ['categoria' => 'Categoría', 'name' => 'Nombre', 'phone' => 'Teléfono', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Detalles'];


foreach ($fields as $value => $key) {

    echo "{$key}: {$posts[$value]}<br>"
}

// Resultado:
// Categoría: zapato
// Nombre: nike
// Teléfono: 666666
// Email: ejemplo@mail.com
// Detalles: hola la quiero
```

Comment: Lo intenté con <br> de la siguiente manera: 

$fields     = array('categoria<br>' => 'Categoría', 'detalles<br>' => 'Detalles', pero el resultado es que omite los campos y no los muestra en el correo. Debo agregarlo en otra parte?

Lo intenté con foreach pero parece que hay un conflicto con otro foreach que tengo: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
Como los puedo integrar?

Comment: @PacoZevallos -  Creo que es esto lo que intentas hacer... (ver edición).. saludos

Comment: Gracias @aldanux me funcionó con el siguiente código: 

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value<br>";
        }
    }

Solo cambié "\n" por "<br>" Gracias por la ayuda.